# Wordpress make entire blog post clickable

Tags: html, wordpress

Currently my blog posts have a small "view more" link at the bottom. Ideally, I would like to change it so that you can click anywhere in the `<article class="blog-post">` and it will link you to the relevant article.

I have figured out how to do it so the excerpt is clickable, but cannot convert it to for the entire article

Code for the excerpt -

```
function clickable_excerpt( $post ) {
    return '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" class="post">'. $post .'</a>';
}
add_filter( 'get_blog_post', 'clickable_excerpt' );
```

Comment: Do you use a free theme? can you share the theme name?

Comment: It is a custom theme I made, but this should be very generic?

Comment: what if you edit the single.php or the template file where you are displaying the blog post and wrap it around the post link?

Comment: For grid post you have to put this link in archive.php under foreach loop while in single post you have to put in single.php/post.php 

this hook not work under foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

Find `class="grid-item"` in your theme code, i found it at `content.php` and then add onclick javascript on article tag, like below

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('grid-item'); ?> onclick="document.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
```

also don't forgot to add CSS

```
article.grid-item {cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_content' ); 

 function filter_content( $content ) { 
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {

        $content = <a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" class="post">'. $content .'</a>;

        }

    return $content;
}
```

Better if you can do it directly in your theme single page template, this link help you to identificate the correct page in your theme:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post